# New indexing in the summation sign

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

[image]Can you help me to write this notation in latex? it is a new symbol and I do not know how to write it in latex.

Answer (score 5):

That's a job for `amsmath`'s `\sideset`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\mysum}{\sideset{}{_{\oplus}}\sum}

\begin{document}
\[
\mysum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} = 1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]